# Python pyautogui error display mouse position

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```

and I get red text error Message like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
  File "C:\Users\NOISEPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1735, in displayMousePosition
    pixelColor = pyscreeze.screenshot().getpixel(
  File "C:\Users\NOISEPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 143, in wrapper
    raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.
```

Comment: install `pillow` `pip install Pillow`

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Pillow package to use pyautogui.displayMousePosition() by using command
first close program window, then open command prompt
the write command given bellow:

pip install Pillow

Then run your code ,it will work fine